# global frame vs. stack frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, stack, global, stack-trace

*Everything below is from the main page of [www.pythontutor.com](http://www.pythontutor.com) (a fantastic tool and website by the way).*

Here's [some code](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20listSum%28numbers%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20not%20numbers%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28f,%20rest%29%20%3D%20numbers%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20f%20%2B%20listSum%28rest%29%0A%0AmyList%20%3D%20%281,%20%282,%20%283,%20None%29%29%29%0Atotal%20%3D%20listSum%28myList%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[image: Here's some code:]

Here's what the author describes as the "global frame" and the "stack frames" at the current point of execution for the above code:

[image: Here's what the author describes as the "global frame" and the "stack frames" at the current point of execution for the above code]

**My question:** What's the difference between "global frame" and the "stack frame"? Is this terminology even correct (I googled around and got all kinds of different answers)?

Comment: "global frame" looks like the name it gives that frame because it is the frame for the global scope, if you are labeling your frames based on the function they are executing this is fairly common.  _The global frame is a stack frame_ usually the one on the very bottom not sure what differences you are really looking for.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Then is it accurate to say that *global frame* is the stack frame for the global scope, and the other *stack frames* are the frames for various local scopes?

Comment: (metaphor) every square is a rectangle, but not every rectangle is a square.  Every "global frame" is a frame in the stack (a "Stack frame") but not all frames in the stack are tied to global scopes.  With a single module it is easy to think of the "global stack" as something much different but really the only difference is that it treats `locals` the same as `globals`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### TL DR:

when you call a function, a frame is created for the local execution.

When a module is loaded, a frame is created for the global module execution.

python tutor doesn't support showing execution across multiple files so the initial frame for the main module can seem like something unique, but you could imagine the statement `import foo` creating a new frame for the execution of the module `foo` just like calling functions creates frames for executing those functions.

---

[`frames`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) are actual python objects that you can interact with:

```
import inspect

my_frame = inspect.currentframe()

print(my_frame) #<frame object at MEMORY_LOCATION>

print(my_frame.f_lineno) #this is line 7 so it prints 7
print(my_frame.f_code.co_filename) #filename of this code executing or '<pyshell#1>' etc.
print(my_frame.f_lineno) #this is line 9 so it prints 9
```

There is nothing particularly special about a global frame vs a local frame - they are just frames in the [`stack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) of execution:

```
Python 3.6.0a1 (v3.6.0a1:5896da372fb0, May 16 2016, 15:20:48) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> import pprint
>>> def test():
...     pprint.pprint(inspect.stack())
... 
>>> test() #shows the frame in test() and global frame
[FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x1003a3be0>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=2, function='test', code_context=None, index=None),
 FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x101574048>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=1, function='<module>', code_context=None, index=None)]
>>> pprint.pprint(inspect.stack()) #only shows global frame
[FrameInfo(frame=<frame object at 0x1004296a8>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=1, function='<module>', code_context=None, index=None)]
```

When ever you call a function (defined with python source code) it will add a frame for it's local execution to the stack, when ever a module is loaded a frame for the global execution of the module is added to the stack.

Frames don't have any standardized naming convention, so terminology accross the internet will probably be contradicting.  Usually you can identify them by the file and function name.  Python refers to global frames as being a function named `<module>` as can be seen in above example (`function='<module>'`) or in errors:

```
>>> raise TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    raise TypeError               # ^ up there
TypeError
```

---

The only real difference between "global" and "function" frames is that with *global frames* there is *no distinction between global and local variables:*

```
>>> my_frame.f_globals is my_frame.f_locals
True
```

Which is why putting the `global` keyword in the global frame is meaningless, it indicates variable names that - when assigned - should be put in `.f_globals` instead of `.f_locals`.  But other then that all frames are pretty much equal.