# Result of -1%7 is different in javascript(-1) and python(6)

Tags: javascript, python, haskell

The expression `-1 % 7` in JavaScript is giving me `-1` as the result. Whereas in Python and Haskell, I found the result to be `6`.

Can anyone explain why both have different behaviors? Which one is correct?

Comment: for python, see http://python-history.blogspot.de/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: See [this article](http://yourdailygeekery.com/2011/06/28/modulo-of-negative-numbers.html) for more information about different behaviors in some languages.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to give a slightly different answer.  As others have said, functions can do whatever you define them to and `m - x = -x` mod `m`.  As a prelude, I'll note that Haskell has two "mod" functions, `mod` and `rem` which differ in just this aspect.  You can make a case that the `mod` one is preferable mathematically.  The `rem` one corresponds to what you'd get on an x86 processor. There is, in fact, a third one, the Euclidean one, which may be even better as well as described by Raymond Boute in [The Euclidean Definitions of the Functions Div and Mod](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2209/353dbdc29032187f19eec4225c702a926b02.pdf).  The third form *always* returns a positive modulus. (There are, in fact, at least two other choices that can be made.)

So, Javascript's definition is what you get from most machine `mod` opcodes.  In this sense, it might be preferable as this would make it more efficient to implement.  Mathematically,  Haskell's and Python's definition is better than Javascript's.  There's also a third definition which may be slightly better.

One key property that the Euclidean and Haskell/Python definitions both possess is `x mod m = y mod m` is equivalent to `x = y` mod `m` which Javascript's definition lacks. You can verify by calculating `6 % 7` in Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct. Some languages return positive modulo numbers, while others retain their sign.

You can simply add the modulus to your variable to get a positive number, or check if the number is positive or negative before performing the modulus operation and correct the result after to switch between the two.

---

Pseudocode to convert `a%b` between the two:

In a language where `-1%7 == -1`, you do this to get a positive number:

```
((a%b)+b) % b
```

And in a language where `-1%7 == 6` you can do this to get the signed version:

```
if a < 0:
  return (a%b)-b
else:
  return a%b
```

Comment: @DanielWagner good catch, I'm too used to not having to worry about overflows. The second one was reversed.

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct, they just use different conventions regarding the handling of negative operands. For positive numbers, the conventions coincide, but for negative numbers they do not. In Python `a % b` always has the same sign as `b`.

In what follows, I'll use Python notation, where `//` is used for integer division.

Let

```python
q, r  = a // b, a % b
```

Then

```python
a == q * b + r
```

**must** be true in any language (assuming `a` and `b` are integers, with `b` not equal to zero). So the way the remainder is handled has to be consistent with the convention used for integer division. In Python, integer division is floor division, i.e., the result is rounded towards negative infinity. In some other languages rounding towards zero is used instead. And in some languages, you get whatever convention the CPU manufacturer decided to implement, so the same code run on different hardware can give different results. As you can imagine, that can be somewhat annoying. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `%` stands for different operators in JavaScript and in Python.

In JavaScript, the `%` stands for the [**Remainder**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) operator. The documentation already points out the difference between the remainder and the modulo operation:

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of the dividend, not the divisor. It uses a built-in modulo function to produce the result, which is the integer remainder of dividing var1 by var2 — for example — var1 modulo var2. There is a proposal to get an actual modulo operator in a future version of ECMAScript, **the difference being that the modulo operator result would take the sign of the divisor, not the dividend.**

<sup>(Emphasis by me)</sup>

In contrast to that: In Python, the `%` stands for the [**modulo**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator. The documentation also makes a statement about the sign:

> The `%` (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. [...] **The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero)**; the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand [2].

<sup>(Emphasis by me)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

To complete the other answers, you can also consider the [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#divmod) function in Python:

> Take two (non complex) numbers as arguments and return a pair of numbers consisting of their quotient and remainder when using integer division. With mixed operand types, the rules for binary arithmetic operators apply. For integers, the result is the same as `(a // b, a % b)`. For floating point numbers the result is `(q, a % b)`, where *q* is usually `math.floor(a / b)` but may be 1 less than that. In any case `q * b + a % b` is very close to *a*, if `a % b` is non-zero it has the same sign as *b*, and `0 <= abs(a % b) < abs(b)`.

```
>>> divmod(-1, 7)
(-1, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Python allows float operands for `//` and `%`. FWIW, `a // b, a % b` can be faster than `divmod(a, b)` due to the extra overhead in calling a function vs using operators, although `divmod` isn't as slow as calling a function written in Python.

Comment: @PM2Ring aren't operators in Python just functions with alternative syntax? I wouldn't think that any modern language with good optimisation has an inevitable performance penalty in using function calls even over built-in operators – if the function is simple enough, it will be inlined anyway.

Comment: @leftaroundabout No, because a function call invokes a new [frame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38938014/4014959) object so that the function's code can run in its own scope. The frame is a fully-fledged Python object so the overhead of doing that is a bit more than calling a C function. Python's optimizer is fairly simple, it doesn't inline function calls. All the previous remarks apply to standard CPython, the details may vary for other implementations.

Comment: @leftaroundabout unfortunately that's not true for CPython. Additionally the Python language semantics make it very difficult to inline function calls.

Comment: And the proof: [Is divmod() faster than using the % and // operators?](//stackoverflow.com/q/30079879)

Comment: @MartijnPieters but CPython isn't really that relevant in performance questions, is it? I added a bounty to that question you've linked to, with regard to how it would look in PyPy.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: ah, didn't see that. I've updated my answer there, on PyPy the difference melts away, but only for integers up to `sys.maxint`.